dashboard that shows uptime percentage from oci-metrics-datasource oci_healthchecks?
I've been asked to create a dashboard to show uptime \ pass rate as a percentage from a high level external monitoring ping to our services rest api.
When importing the data into Grafana, using the oci-metrics-datasource data source, it appears to come in sort of like below



Date time
Healthcheck A
Healthcheck B
Healthcheck C
Healthcheck D




2024-10-10_01:30:00
1
1
0
1


2024-10-10_01:35:00
1
0
0
1


2024-10-10_01:40:00
1
1
1
1



With 1's representing a pass and 0's representing a fail. I'd like to represent this as a gauge, but I'm not that fussy.
I understand that I need to count the 1's and count the 0's, then divide them and multiple by 100. The maths is simple, but I cannot get Grafana to do it.
Is there anyone here who can assist me?

How do you want to see the gauge?  I do not see much choice when having only values 0 and 1.....  (https://i.sstatic.net/rqcGgDkZ.png)

As percentages. So Healthcheck A with 99.9%

But, seeing 0 at Healthcheck_B on 01:35:00,  what percentage should be shown for B ?  How long does this 0` influence the value shown by the gauge?    (P.S. I do not have experience in grafana, so do not expect an answer from /me, I am just trying to get more info, so someone can help your)

Not familiar with oci monitoring, but I guess you can't process data on their end, and have to everything in Grafana?

If so, generally you might try converting your data into separate time series, and then aggregating their values using Mean.

https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/21069-oci-monitoring/ should get you started?

@Luuk that doesn't contain the information we're after. While it's comprehensive, it still misses the mark.
